# How to print predication without the inputs (features)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

How to print Predicted results without the inputs (features)?

This is what I'm getting:

> X=[-0.53268208 -0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829  2.44948974 -0.40824829 -0.40824829], Predicted=0
>
> X=[-0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829  2.44948974
> -0.40824829  1.02265268], Predicted=1

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

> Predicted=0
>
> Predicted=1

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Xnew, _ = X_train_scaled, Y_train
# make a prediction
ynew = loaded_model.predict(Xnew)
# show the inputs and predicted outputs
for i in range(len(Xnew)):
print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (Xnew[i], ynew[i]))
```

Comment: It's printing exactly what you're telling it to print. Just take the unwanted values out of your print statement.

Comment: Thank you @G.Anderson for the reply; i'm new at this and have tried omitting different parts of the code in hopes to get a "cleaner" print results. However, i kept keeping error messages, hence, i'm posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just choose to not print it at all. I believe that you would still need some identifier to map the predictions to the feature samples.

```py
....
     print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (i, ynew[i]))
....
```

Comment: Thank you @Gokul Krishnan R, the code worked; however, is there anyway to omit the X=1, X=2,...etc? This is what im getting now; X=1, Predicted=1

Comment: print("Predicted=%s" % (ynew[i])). I don't understand how you would find it intelligible.

Comment: i don't find it intelligible (it is all good), i was just hoping to learn a little more on how to alter the codes. Many thanks